# How the propagation of cylindrical waves looks like in z direction?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics

When calculating the propagation of cylindrical wave in cylindrical coordinates $(r,\varphi,z)$ we usually consider that Hertz vector is nonzero only in $z$ direction. Why exactly we make this assumption?

Also, I can quite imagine what happens in $r$-direction of a propagation where Bessel functions are the solutions. In $z$ direction the solution is

$T(z)=A\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\beta z}+B\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\beta z}$,

where $\beta$ is a constant. Should I imagine this as something like a superposition of two harmonic waves oscillating up and down the z-axis?

Answer (score 0):

"When calculating the propagation of cylindrical wave in cylindrical coordinates (r,φ,z) we usually consider that Hertz vector is nonzero only in z direction. Why exactly we make this assumption?"

As far as I remember, one can present any electromagnetic field in homogeneous media using electric and magnetic Hertz potentials (in a general case, you need both of them) whose $x$- and $y$-components vanish.

"Should I imagine this as something like a superposition of two harmonic waves oscillating up and down the z-axis?"

I would say it's just a superposition of two cylindrical waves propagating in two opposite directions (towards $z=+\infty$ and $z=-\infty$ (I could say more if you explained what $A$ and $B$ mean), but you need to remember that exponential functions of an imaginary argument appear when you assume that actual fields are the real parts of complex fields.